# Websockets online deployment

Tags: php, html, websocket

I am working on a web development project involving websockets.
Every thing is all right on local server, using wamp server.

Problems occurred online, the dedicated server is well configured for websocket (php extension is activated) and I can run the server without any problem.

Nevertheless the connection fails, client is unable to be connected. This is not a problem of port or firewall, client can access to the server but the handshake stay uncompleted.

I use [PHPWebSocket](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/class.PHPWebSocket.php) :

There isn't lots of documentation about websockets deployment on a web server, it works generaly fine in local.

If someone have encountered the same problem or have an idea of what's going wrong...

Comment: Are you sure there is no firewall or routing ? Some proxy (like mod_proxy) can break websocket communications.

Comment: Did a firewall should have directly block the connection?

Comment: It may be unable to transfer it correctly, if it doesn't know how to handle this specific case and makes incorrect (obsolete) assumptions regarding http. I'm sure about some proxies being incompatible, I don't know for firewalls but it may be possible.

Comment: How to be sure this is not a firewall problem? And for proxy?

Comment: For the firewall, test from another point if you suspect the client one. Regarding server firewall and proxy, don't you know the ones you're using ?

Comment: mmh the client one seems ok, for the server, i'll get informations about it asap

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

PHPwebsocket use IDs to differentiate client and associated sockets.

So, on the $this->read, we have some couples :

clientID => sockets

The problem is there,  the function socket_select don't care about id. So depending of the implementation...

**on local (Windows)**

input :

```
{
0 => ressource #5,
1 => ressource #6
}
```

output :

```
{
**1** => ressource #6
}
```

**online (Debian)**

input :

```
{
0 => ressource #5,
1 => ressource #6
}
```

output :

```
{
**0** => ressource #6
}
```

The relation is not keep anymore on the second case, which cause a problem on the rest of the process.

To resolve that problem, I add a loop to redefined id :

```
foreach($this->wsRead as $id => $socket2){
    if($socket2 ==$socket)
    $clientID = $id;
    }
```

After the loop $clientID is set to the right value.